# Ubuntu 18.04 Disable WiFi Device and enable Broadcomm connection on startup

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, startup, mobile-broadband

Back to Ubuntu after years in MS.

In Ubuntu Bionic Beaver:

1. How to automatically disable Wifi device on startup?
2. How to turn "Mobile Broadband = enabled" on startup?

WiFi hardware: Intel Wireless 7260 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260)
WiFi device :  wlp4s0
WiFi driver :  iwlwifi

4G hardware: Sierra 4G
4G device :  cdc-wdm1
4G driver :  gsm (cdc_acm, cdc_mbim)

thnx in advance.